# Windows 7 Won't Boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

I recently built a new computer, my fifth one.

- ASUS Maximus III Formula LGA 1156 Intel P55 ATX Motherboard
- EVGA 01G-P3-1452-TR GeForce GTS 450 Superclocked 1GB 128-bit  GDDR5 PCI Express 2.0 x16 HDCP Video Card
- COOLMAX RM-1000B 1000W ATX psu
- Intel Core i7-875K lynnfield 2.93GHz LGA 1156 95w Quad-Core unlocked processor
- G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 16 (4x4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1333 (PC3 10666) memory
- WD VelociRaptor WD3000GLFS 300gb 10000 RPM SATA 3.0Gb/s Hard Drive
- Sony Optiarc CD/DVD Burner model AD-7261S-0B LightScribe
- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

It gets hung up on the starting windows screen. When I went to install the OS it did the same thing wouldn't go past the windows logo, so I put the new HDD into my old computer and installed windows 7 thinking it was just an installer error.

Put the fully installed HDD back into my new machine and it still gets stuck on the starting windows screen. I've tried most everything I've looked up. Disabled USB, Disabled Turbo Boost, Disabled everything that wasn't essential(just about every configuration I can think of), took it apart and put it back together, took all the ram out save one 4g stick(wouldn't even boot when I did this), did a memory scan which came back successful, I don't know what could be wrong.

Only thing I can think of is a compatibility issue somewhere, but I've ran over it again and again and I don't know where there would be an issue like that.

Need Backup! >.<

Comment: is the SATA controller set to AHCI, IDE or RAID mode?

Comment: It is set as IDE

Comment: are you able to boot into safe mode?

Comment: It's going. very slowly though, hasn't froze yet. I'll give an update in a few. it's bearly moving if at all. in safe mode

Comment: Well by golly g that's all it took. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Vie have you updated the Motherboard BIOS ?

Comment: i am guessing from your follow-up that it is booting correctly now. if so, probably what happened was after being installed on the old computer there were incorrect drivers being loaded (different hardware) and booting into safemode allowed it to detect and install software for the new hardware.

Answer (score -1):

(Presumed answer from comments)

Boot the computer in safe-mode, allowing the OS to detect driver issues and install updates for any drivers that may have been disallowing boot.